# Google Analytics - Events - Category, Action & Label are not enough

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I would like to send event that includes all kind of parameters and then to be able to slice it in the UI for each parameter.

Currently AFAIK I got only three parameters: Category, Action & Label.

I develop a tracking time app and I want to send an event when a user clock in.
So an example of event would be:
 1. Company of user
 2. User id
 3. clock-in
 4. Section inside the app the user clocked-in from

Eventually I would like to slice the data in Analytics UI in all kinds of way:
 1. How many clock-ins per Company
 2. How many clock-ins per User
 3. How many clock-ins made from section1

How can I achieve that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the answer is [custom dimenstions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en) (Thanks @KatherineR).
Category, Action & Label are dimensions and you have the ability to add dimensions of your own.

1. To add custom dimension:
   Admin --> under "Property" column - Custom Defintions --> Custom dimension.
   Each custom dimension has a [scope](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en#example-hit) - I used Hit-Level scope.
2. Code:

   ```
   ga('send', 'event', gaCategory, gaAction, gaLabel, {
       'dimension1': companyName,
       'dimension2': userId
   });
   ```

   Please note the keys should be dimensionN, where n=[1..9].
   the n is then index of the custom dimensions you defined in section 1.
3. Now in GA ui you can create your new report which include your new custom dimensions.
   Customization --> Custom reports --> create new report
   In the "Report content" --> Dimenstions --> include your new dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

This is something that [custom dimensions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en) could help with.

1. First of all, make sure you have user analysis set to 'on' in your
   google analytics settings, and [set up tracking for users](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666?hl=en). You will then set the user id when the session starts like so:

   `ga('set', 'userId', 'my_user_id_123');`
2. For company of the user, you will want to send a custom dimension. First, set up the custom dimension [in the account settings](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829). Then, just make another set call similar to how you identify the user in step 1:

   `ga('set', 'company', 'AwesomeCompanyId');`
3. For clock-in and section, I think the event category / action / label should be enough to track what you need. I would suggest `category: 'clockin'` `action: 'clock-in'` `label: 'section A'`

   ````
   ga('send', 'event', ‘clock-in’, ‘clock-in’, ‘section A’);```
   ````

You can then start using [custom dimension vs custom event](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7084499?hl=en) reports to answer the questions you have.

Comment: I removed the bit about custom variables, as these are deprecated since 2012.

Comment: Thanks @EikePierstorff

Comment: @KatherineR Do I need to ga('set', 'company', company) before every ga('send', 'event',...) ?